# Unable to update integers in PGDB table field using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

```
Dim pLinerow As IRow
pLinerow = ptable.CreateRow  
pLinerow.Value(pLinerow.Fields.FindField("IS_CLOSED")) = 0
```

when this code is executed,  the below mentioned error is returned,

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component"

Comment: Are you able to update this field's value with the arcmap field calculator?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas to check:

1. Have you confirmed that you created a valid pTable object and it's not actually Nothing?
2. Does IS_CLOSED exist in the table?
3. If IS_CLOSED exists is it actually a numeric field?